Complete ionization temperature of an atom
If you google at which temperature hydrogen and helium are ionized completely, so that there is theoretically only a nucleus left, the given answers are around 10000K and 29000K respectively. Is there an equation that could predict the complete ionization temperature of various atoms, and is there experimental data on this subject?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saha_ionization_equation

Yes I am aware of the existence of Saha equation but I was hoping to come across a different equation since I am not sure how it works. I have made a new equation, which I don't know if it's accurate. For example, my equation gives the complete ionization temperatures for hydrogen and helium respectively as 12561,69K and 30287,00K. That's why I am looking for experimental data as well.

I think the question is slightly misposed: For hydrogen the Saha equation gives (Ionization energy $I_e$=13.6eV)
\begin{align}
\frac{n_\text{e} n_\text{p}}{n_\text{H}}=\frac{n^2_\text{Ion}}{n-n_\text{Ion}}=\frac{(2\pi m_e kT)^{3/2}}{h^3}e^{-I_e/kT}
\end{align}
So you see that the ionization rate $n_\text{Ion}/n$ actually depends on the temperature $T$ on the (initial) density of the hydrogen gas $n$, see plot:
$n_{Ion}/n$" />

If we don't over interpret OP and take the question very literally, the desired answer is the temperature scale that is comparable to the energy required to remove the innermost electron:
$$
T \sim Z(13.6 \text{eV})/k_B
$$

deepest core electron binding energy doesn't scale linearly with $Z$.

https://xdb.lbl.gov/Section1/Table_1-1.pdf
